# How to align these two columns

Tags: two-column, apa6

Note: I'm new to LaTeX.

[image]

The bottoms of these two columns don't line up.

I'd like to find a way to make them line up.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,jou]{apa6}
\setlength\parindent{1cm}

\title{\textbf{Title}\\\Large{small title}}

\fiveauthors{Name}{Name}{Name}{Name}{Name}

\fiveaffiliations{\textit{name}}{\textit{name}}{\textit{name}}{\textit{name}}{\textit{name}}

\rightheader{eh}
\leftheader{eh}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\noindent
\textbf{Abstract}
\\\indent
Words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words
\\

\noindent
\textbf{1. Introduction}
\\\indent
Words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words 

\end{document}
```

If I remove the "\\indent" then columns line up but with a weird full line break between paragraphs in the introduction, which I don't want either.

EDIT: A combination of changing to section titles, \raggedbottom, and \flushbottom worked, but now there's still a slight space between two paragraphs on the first page that's inconsistent with the rest of the paragraphs in the paper. [image]

It's not horrible but I'd like to see if there's any way to get rid of that.

Comment: have a look at [How to align text position on both sides of a twocolumn layout](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65838/how-to-align-text-position-on-both-sides-of-a-twocolumn-layout). Also, you should probably use `\section*{Abstract}`, and `\section{Introduction}` for numbered section. Don't use ``\\`` in text, just leave an empty line. `\indent` is also not necessary here.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `\raggedbottom` to the code achieves the desired alignment for the MWE; I tried it myself. If this is not a general answer, then someone please explain why.